# EXCEL Pivot Table not showing all the months

Tags: excel, excel-2021

I was trying to make a Pivot Table and I cannot understand what could be wrong. I want to display all the months in the Row Labels but it only displays the month of January. (I'm using Excel 2021.)
Link to the dataset: [link to dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZzfjZHr_CUctMv3pYcsh1P12r1-F4QXxxZTa8BWP8-4/edit#gid=315377254)

Here you can see, it only shows the month of January. [Screenshot of my Excel showing the month of Jan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dxnZ.png)

I tried in google sheets and it works perfectly fine but I can't seem to understand why is it a problem in my Excel 2021.
[What I am expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmRIg.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely your system thinks these are all American format dates so 01 is being taken as January not the first of the month.

I formatted them as UK style and Pivot Table works fine (apart from that one odd value):-

[image: Pivot Table by months]